# Getting one function to call another function that creates tuple

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'm trying to get my results function to call my retrieve_pub_vote_summary function, which creates a tuple. I then want my results function to print the tuple.

```
@application.route('/results/')
def results:
    publication = "nytimes"
    retrieve_pub_vote_summary(publication)
    print(pub_tuple)

##############################################
def retrieve_pub_vote_summary(publication):
    onevotes = 1
    twovotes = 2
    pub_tuple = (onevotes, twovotes)
    print(pub_tuple)
    return pub_tuple
```

pub_tuple prints fine in retrieve_pub_vote_summary. But it doesn't seem to go to results. I get "NameError: name 'pub_tuple' is not defined."

Comment: pub_tuple = retrieve_pub_vote_summary(publication). You need to assign it to the variable.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I store a result of a function in a variable in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35423564/how-can-i-store-a-result-of-a-function-in-a-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 errors in the code:

```
def results():                                          # added ()
    publication = "nytimes"
    pub_tuple = retrieve_pub_vote_summary(publication)  # assign the result
    print(pub_tuple)                                    # now pub_tuple is defined the line above


##############################################
def retrieve_pub_vote_summary(publication):
    onevotes = 1
    twovotes = 2
    pub_tuple = (onevotes, twovotes)
    print(pub_tuple)
    return pub_tuple


results()   # call results
```

Now it returns

```
(1, 2)
(1, 2)
```

*pub_tuple* in *retrieve_pub_vote_summary* is a **local variable** inside retrieve_pub_vote_summary. That's why it couldn't be printed and you got the error.